# How to specify filter policy while creating subscription on aws sns?

Tags: amazon-sns

I want to create a SNS subscription to an existing topic through the java sdk.
In all [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/example_sns_SetSubscriptionAttributes_section.html) I saw that a filter policy is linked to an existing subscription.

Is it possible to set a filter policy during a SNS subscription?